# When to use and not use java futures?

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, future

While going through asynchronous programming in java I came across Futures. As far as I could understand, we use futures by returning an object of a future type if we want to use the result of this asynchronous methods in our method. As in my thread blocks on some other requirement, then this async process is picked up and it replaces the future objects placeholder, so that it can then be used by the caller method. Am I correct in assuming this?

But what if in my use case the api I create doesn't need the result of the async method? As in, lets say my requirement sort of looks like this.

```
int addInts(int x, int y) {
    int z = x+y;
    store_result(x, y, z);
    return z;
}

@Async
void store_result(int x, int y, int z) {
    //persist these results in some db or call some other api here
}
```

So addInts 'll just sum up the integers and return the result and as I don't want to wait till the result is stored, I put it in an asynchronous method which I'm not very dependent on anyway.

So in this case I don't need to use futures right?

EDIT:
Also Why would I need to define a custom task executor bean when spring by default creates a simple SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor bean for you?

Answer (score 0):

> Also Why would I need to define a custom task executor bean when
>   spring by default creates a simple SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor bean for
>   you

You haven't specified you're on the Spring stack. If that's ok for you, annotating your method with `@Async` is sufficient for it to be run via a pre-configured `ExecutorService` or `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`.

---

With this piece of code

```
store_result(x, y, z);
return z;
```

do you expect `store_result` to update the `z` value? Because that won't happen, as `z` is of a primitive type, and they're passed by value, which means their value is copied. But yeah, I think this was just an example.

---

And no, in that case you don't need a `Future<T>`. However you might want to get a hold on it when potentially having to `cancel` the task, or when interested in the status (`done`, `canceled`).

An example of `Future<T>` usage might be

```
int addInts(int x, int y) {
    final int z = x + y;
    final Future<Integer> result = executorService.submit(new StoreResultCallable(z));

    // Continue the method execution

    // Now we are at the end of the method. We ask our Future<Integer>
    // if the result of the computation is ready. If it is ready, it will immediatly return,
    // otherwise the execution will be blocked (with a possible predefined timeout value)
    return result.get();
}
```

Comment: No, I don't expect store_result to update z. Here store_result is just a method which persists these values in a db or maybe send these values to another api which 'll use them.

Comment: @user3248186 okay. My answer still holds valid.

Comment: Running an asynchronous operation and not caring about what it does is always a little suspicious. In particular, you generally should be interested in whether it succeeded or failed, even if it doesn't need to return a "result".

Comment: @another-dave sure. I was just answering the question. There are however certain type of task which are "launch and forget".

Comment: My intent was to add a comment for the OP, not to criticize your answer (which I upvoted).